# Is it possible to store a geometry datatype in mysql 5.6 by using Hibernate-Spatial API?

Tags: hibernate-spatial

I would like to persist co-ordinates of polygon shape in Mysql5.6. I have seen tutorial for Postgresql. http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/02-Tutorial/01-tutorial4/

But They haven't specified any sample code for mysql. So I feel fear to start with. Please suggest me, Is it possible to persist a single polygon shape in mysql database ?

Regards,
ArunRaj.

Comment: Don't use mysql for GIS, support is half-baked, use postgis instead

Comment: @hd1 : We can not use postgis. May I know what are all the features have not been baked ?

Comment: Just google it... for starters, there's [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29587/mysql-geospatial-function-for-st-distance-spheroid-metric-used-in-return-type-o]) SO question for one of the limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, We can store and retrieve the spatial datatype by hibernate spatial API. The tutorial Which i was mentioned is enough to store and retrieve the spatial data.